# Media file repair tool

Tags: repair, mp4, aac

I have an incomplete MP4 file. It contains audio only, in AAC. Is there any way to fix the file so I can play the partial file?

Comment: maybe one of these http://www.videohelp.com/tools/sections/video-repair-fix

Comment: I tried http://www.filerepair1.com/ and it didn't work

Comment: the free version of [qtatomviewer](http://tsviatko.jongov.com/index_prj_quicktimeviewer.htm) didn't work

Comment: did you tried any mp3 cutter/joiner aplication??? I should try to open it and cut off the last media second. Take a look at here: http://www.baixaki.com.br/download/mp3-cutter.htm

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha I tried this one http://www.mp3cutter.org/ and it didn't work

Comment: How did it become incomplete? As it is you give us zero to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy out.aac
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in VLC Player or something that would give you verbose error messages. If the error is something like

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9000a0] moov atom not found
```

then you are out of luck. You need to have the beginning and also the end of the file, because the important headers are stored there. Many Torrent clients have the option to prioritize downloading t